# NetBeans - How to stop the reformat feature from expanding braces into new line

Tags: javascript, netbeans

I have some JavaScript code that I like to keep concise with statements like

```
if (!this.grid) { return; }
```

However, I often find myself needing to run the NetBeans "reformatter" feature, using the shortcut Ctrl-Shift-F. Whenever I do this, it expands the above line of code into

```
if (!this.grid) {
    return;
}
```

Is there a way to stop NetBeans from doing this? I'm using NetBeans 7.2.1 on OS X.